# Error authenticating client AuthSdkError: OAuth flow timed out

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, okta

Okta is timing out for some of our users when they are logging into our application which uses Okta as an IDP. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

```
OAuthUtil-okta.js:45 Error authenticating client AuthSdkError: OAuth flow timed out
(anonymous) @ OAuthUtil-okta.js:45
Promise.catch (async)
(anonymous) @ OAuthUtil-okta.js:44
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ OAuthUtil-okta.js:25
Promise.then (async)
requestAccessToken @ OAuthUtil-okta.js:22
apply @ lodash.js:474
wrapper @ lodash.js:5337
testForOAuthToken @ AuthenticationUtil-okta.js:56
loginWithCurrentCookies @ AuthenticationUtil-okta.js:62
apply @ lodash.js:475
wrapper @ lodash.js:5337
(anonymous) @ module-okta.js:105
invoke @ angular.js:5208
(anonymous) @ angular.js:5007
forEach @ angular.js:388
createInjector @ angular.js:5007
doBootstrap @ angular.js:1963
bootstrap @ angular.js:1984
__webpack_exports__.default @ auth-initial.js:102
./common/webpack.entry.js @ webpack.entry.js:57
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:19
(anonymous) @ bootstrap:68
(anonymous) @ bootstrap:68
```